# CSS: Child menu of child menu absolute positioning

Tags: css, list, parent-child

The menu on this page: http://goldencraft.co/wp/

CSS: http://goldencraft.co/wp/wp-content/themes/minecraft/style.css

Hover over `My Account` then `View Order`. I want the `View Order` child list to be positioned to the right (absolutely beside `View Order`). If you look at the CSS (see above), you will notice that I do not specify `min-width` or `width` properties other than `auto` or `100%` and that is not about to change.

I'm just looking for a way to move a 2nd child list to the right of it's parent.

Comment: This seems to have disappeared from view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now just add this css in your stylesheet

```
.sub-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: -109px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Result is

[image]

Comment: Forget that deleted comment, my CSS was on crack. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at it again? How could I make it support multiple sub-childs? (`View Order` works, but `Change Password` is now wrong because there's 2 sub-menu's`); Like is there a way to make the sub-menu dynamically move itself (using only CSS)?

Comment: @BrianGraham now define .sub-menu li ul.sub-menu{width:100%;}